# Get the background color of textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to Jquery , please pardon my ignorance. I have a page where I set textboxes with different colors on page load, the requirement is to filter on a particular color i.e to display only 1 color on click of particular checkbox.

What I'm trying to do:
I'm traversing through the html table row by row, trying to get the current color of each text box, if the color matches keep it else hide the row where the textbox color does not match. I have seen various posts which show how to set the color but not how to retrieve the current color of the textBox, tried on the same lines but no luck, please help.

```
$('input[id$=cbx]').click(function () {
 var v = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox3.ClientID%>");
 // to get the color value of current text box
 var v2 = v.style.background 
 // below also does not work
 var v2 = v.style.background.val()
 // below also does not work
 var v3= v.css('background-color');
 if (v2 == "green")
  {
   $('[id$=user1]').hide();
  }
```

Comment: Add html mark up?

Comment: Why it is tagged to c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the propbelm is with this line. Since you have not shared the `HTML` it is not possible to understand if there is a `style` attribute to this element.

```
v.style.background
```

If there is no style attribute `v.style` will give [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) but all will have empty value.

If there is a style attribute defined in the element like this below example

**HTML**

```
<input id= "abc" type = "text" class = "red" style = "background:red">
```

**JS**

```
var v = document.getElementById("abc");
var v2 = v.style.background 
console.log(v.style.background); // red
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/38wLk9x6/1/)

will log `red`

If there is no style attribute defined on the element, you can use `getComputedStyle` property to get the value. But in this case the value will be in `rgb` format.

```
var v = document.getElementById("abc");
var v2 = window.getComputedStyle(v, null);
console.log(v2.background)
```

[**DEMO2**](https://jsfiddle.net/38wLk9x6/)

Comment: Great answer explain every thing .

Comment: The html is this <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" BackColor="Green"></asp:TextBox>, i shall try your suggetion, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

'green' is rgb(0, 128, 0)
try this one.

```
$('input[id$=cbx]').click(function () {
    var v = $('#<%=TextBox3.ClientID').css('background-color');
    if( v== 'rgb(0, 128, 0)') {
        $('[id$=user1]').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get background color using jQuery as follows

```
var bgColor = $('#textbox-id-here').css('background-color');
```

You will get RGB value. If you want to convert this to hex value, you can use following function

```
function rgb2hex(rgb){
 rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba?[\s+]?\([\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?/i);
 return (rgb && rgb.length === 4) ? "#" +
  ("0" + parseInt(rgb[1],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
  ("0" + parseInt(rgb[2],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
  ("0" + parseInt(rgb[3],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) : '';
}
```

**EDIT**

Assume you have table to hold your textboxes. then you can do something like this

```
$('#table-id tr td input[type=text]').each(function(){
  var bg = rgb2hex($(this).css('background-color'));
  if(bg==='#ff0000'){
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```